# Trying to get webView to load 2 URLS after another

Tags: swift, webview, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

Im trying to make it load 2 webviews after one gets finished loading
then it will go to the next one and start to load that one and if both of them are loaded it will send a notification.

It gives an error after

```
        @IBAction func MybuttonAction(_ sender: Any) {

    if !googleLoaded {

        googleLoaded = true
        let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")
        let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
        print("Google loaded")
        let url1 = URL(string: "https://yahoo.com")
        let requestObj1 = URLRequest(url: url1!)
        webView.loadRequest(requestObj1)
        print("yahoo loaded")

    } else if !yahooLoaded {

        yahooLoaded = true

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "ThankYou", message: "Both Views have finished loading", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.aviLoadingSpinner.stopAnimating()
    }
}


func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use UIWebViewDelegate webViewDidFinishLoad. That method is called when a request is completed.

```
import WebKit

class yourViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

 @IBoutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

 var googleLoaded: Bool = false 
 var yahooLoaded: Bool = false 

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     self.webView.delegate = self
 }         

 func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

     if !googleLoaded { 

         googleLoaded = true
         let url = URL(string: "https://yahoo.com")
         let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url!)
         webView.loadRequest(requestObj) 

     } else if !yahooLoaded { 

         yahooLoaded = true
         let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "ThankYou", message: "Both Views have finished loading", preferredStyle: .alert)

         let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
         alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

         self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
         self.aviLoadingSpinner.stopAnimating() 
     }
 }

 @IBAction func MybuttonAction(_ sender: Any) {

     let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")
     let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url!)
     webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
}
```

Comment: Hmm im not sure how could i add that to a code? like how can i write that in a complete code?

if !googleLoaded { 
    googleLoaded = true
    //request for yahoo 

} else if !yahooLoaded { 
   yahooLoaded = true
   //notification 
}

what is the value of googleLoaded?

Comment: both false because you initialize variable as false, once the first request (google) finish, it sets true and request yahoo. When the second request (yahoo) finish, it sets true and send notification. Hope it helps!

Comment: how could i put googleLoaded and yahooLoaded to a URL String?

Comment: googleLoaded and yahooLoaded are bools that allows your code to say: ok, its googleLoaded? or its yahoo? you must do the first request in viewdidload and the other on webDidFinishLoad method. I will update my answer

Comment: when i press the button 1 time it goes to google and when google finishes loading completely it stays at google it doesnt switch to yahoo.com 

How can i make it load another after it being finished and refresh it everytime its pressed?

I admire your help! Thank you

Comment: o i forget a line of code. in your viewDidLoad add this: webView.delegate = self

Comment: I already had that in my webview, the problem is that i have to press the button a second time to get to the next yahoo but i want it to check automatically if google finishes loading it should load yahoo right away instead of pressing it a second time, it does its scan for loaded webpages and sends the alert notification saying they both have finshed running do you know what i mean?

Comment: Yeah i understand you and i tested my answer code, it works! First load Google and when it finish load yahoo automatically

Comment: i updated my answer too, thats exactly what you should do

Comment: Good job Lucas! Thank you! +++++

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly what you now have is

- Check if webview is loading
- the first time you press a button it shouldn't be loading so load yahoo
- the second time you press the button it sees the webview loading so it loads google.com
- after that you check if it is finished loading.

but a few problems with this is, you have to press the button twice, which i assume you don't want. The way you have it now doesn't load google before yahoo which your comments tell me. And if you do it like this it starts loading google while yahoo COULD be still loading.
I would do it like this :

```
let url = URL (string: "https://google.com")
let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url!)
webView.loadRequest(requestObj)

while webview.IsLoading{
// you should wait here
}
let url = URL (string: "https://yahoo.com")
let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url!)
webView.loadRequest(requestObj)

while webview.IsLoading{
//You should wait again here     
}


//Now you don't have to check anymore to see if they are done
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "ThankYou", message: "Both Views have finished loading", preferredStyle: .alert)

let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
self.aviLoadingSpinner.stopAnimating()
```

This way you first load google. you wait until it finished loading.
Then you load yahoo and wait.
And after that you start the notification.

Comment: Ok, so i inputted and made the adjustments but i now get and error saying

Value of type 'UIWebView' has no member 'isLoading'

Comment: Hmm I assumed isLoading existed because you used it yourself. You should try @Lucas's answer. He uses  `webViewDidFinishLoad`